# mutated function in several columns

Tags: r, loops, mutated

I have a data frame like this one, with several rows for the same subject

```
ID  alcohol_1   alcohol_2
1   1           0
1   0           1
2   0           1
2   0           0
```

When I have "1" for the alcohol_1 and alcohol_2 columns, I would like to be able to repeat them on all the rows of the same subject to have a df like this

```
 ID alcohol_1   alcohol_2
 1  1           1
 1  1           1
 2  0           1
 2  0           1
```

I can do it column by column with these functions:

```
df<-df%>%
  group_by(ID) %>%  mutate(alcohol_1= max(alcohol_1))

df<-df%>%
  group_by(ID) %>%  mutate(alcohol_2 = max(alcohol_2))
```

But I would like to be able to automate this (with a function, a loop or whatever) as I have many more columns in my real df.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Refer `dplyr::across` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

Comment: Something like `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(across(starts_with("alcohol_"), max))`

Comment: Thank you! I adapted the code a bit and it seems to work                    df %>% group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(across(c(4:237), max))